# free() errors and munmap_chunk errors when exiting a program

Tags: c, linux, string, token

I wrote a program in C that tokenizes an input string, and when the user enters "exit", it exits the program.

It seems to tokenize the string correctly, however, when I exit the program, I get an error either about an "aborted (core dumped) error" about freeing memory, or a munmap_chunk error.

Here is the link to the picture of my output:

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLru0.png)

And here is my code for the program:

```
int main() {
   /* Main Function Variables */
   char *buf;
   char *token;
   size_t num_chars;
   size_t bufsize = 2048;
   int run = 1;
   int tok_count = 0;
   int cmp;

   /* Allocate memory for the input buffer. */
   buf = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);

   /*main run loop*/
   while(run) {
       /* Print >>> then get the input string */
       printf(">>> ");
       num_chars = getline(&buf, &bufsize, stdin);

       cmp = strcmp(buf, "exit\n");

       if (num_chars > 1) {
         /* Tokenize the input string */
         if (cmp != 0) {
              /* Display each token */
              while((token = strtok_r(buf, " ", &buf))) {
                    printf("T%d: %s\n", tok_count, token);
                    tok_count++;
                }
         }
         /* If the user entered <exit> then exit the loop */
         else {
             run = 0;
             break;
         }
     }
     tok_count = 0;
   }

   /*Free the allocated memory*/
   free(buf);
   return 1;
}
```

What may be the problem here that is causing the free() errors and munmap_chunk errors?

Comment: Have you built your program with the address sanitizer turned on?  Or tried running your program through valgrind?  Either should really help triage memory issues.

Comment: `strtok_r(buf, " ", &buf)` will modify `buf`, so that when you pass it to `getline` or `free` it's no longer the same pointer allocated by `malloc` or `getline`.  Make a copy to pass to `strtok_r`.